# VS 2008 crashes after Anti-XSS added

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-2, xss, antixsslibrary

Hello I'm using visual studio 2008 with asp.net mvc 2. I need anti xss library to santitize an input which is generated by rich text editor (lightweight RTE).
I want to use AntiXss.GetSafeHtmlFragment(input);  function.

the problem is that VS 2008 crashes after I reference anti xss dll (it works fine in the first time but than it crashes).

Does anybody how to fix this problem?
If not can somebody point me to a working altrenative ( I tried using html agility pack while allowing a white list but I have only managed to allow tags without attributes).

the code for the html agility filter -

```
  public static string Filter(string html, string[] allowedTags)
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            Process(doc.DocumentNode, buffer, allowedTags);
            return buffer.ToString();
        }
        static string[] RemoveChildrenOfTags = new string[] { "script", "style" };
        static void Process(HtmlNode node, StringBuilder buffer, string[] allowedTags)
        {
            switch (node.NodeType)
            {
                case HtmlNodeType.Text:
                    buffer.Append(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(((HtmlTextNode)node).Text));
                    break;
                case HtmlNodeType.Element:
                case HtmlNodeType.Document:
                    bool allowedTag = allowedTags.Contains(node.Name.ToLower());
                    if (allowedTag)
                        buffer.AppendFormat("<{0}>", node.Name);
                    if (!RemoveChildrenOfTags.Contains(node.Name))
                        foreach (HtmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
                            Process(childNode, buffer, allowedTags);
                    if (allowedTag)
                        buffer.AppendFormat("</{0}>", node.Name);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found why VS 2008 is crushing when refrencing to AntiXss- it's because of power commands addin for VS 2008. removed it and it's fine.